# Closing a Plasmid by Ligation

Tags: pcr, cloning, ligation

I have been having trouble with what should be a fairly simple ligation. I had a plasmid that I needed to cut part out of, so I designed a couple PCR primers to do that. The plasmid already had a BamHI site on 1 side of the region I wanted to remove, so I made the other PCR primer with a BamHI site on its 5' end with 3 extra Cs so the restriction enzyme would bind better. Here is a crude diagram of what I tried to do:

[image]

So I did the PCR and BamHI digest, it looked good on gel, so I purified it from the gel, got the concentration on the Nanodrop, and set up a ligation.

However, I keep getting zero colonies. I have tried a 24 hour reaction at 4 degrees, and 10 minute reaction at room temp. I am currently trying a reaction where I supplement the buffer with fresh ATP, because the buffers are a little old. If that works, problem solved, if not, I am asking how to troubleshoot this.

This seems like it should be relatively simple, because I have no insert, just trying to close an empty vector, which seems to happen on its own when I don't want it to and dephosphorylate the vector.

UPDATE:

The reaction with extra ATP did not produce colonies. I will keep trying. One idea I had was to do the PCR and then try blunt end ligation, since the Pfu polymerase should make blunt ends. Also got a new sample of ligase.

Comment: Can you heat inhibit your restriction enzyme and go straight to ligation without the purification step? I am asking because gel purification (or column purification) sometimes trim a bit the end and interfere with the ligation. This is quite rare but might have happen to you.

Comment: @cagliari2005 According the NEB poster on my wall, BamHI probably can't be heat denatured.

Comment: 1. How do you know the BamHI enzyme is working? 2. How do you know the ligase is working? 3. How do you know the cells are actually competent? 4. What is the selectable marker--is that the same drug in your plates?

Comment: @mdperry The removed sections are too small to tell if the digest worked, but the same BamHI batch works for other plasmids with visible fragments. The same batches of cells produced colonies when transformed with intact plasmid. The plasmid has an ampicillin resistance gene, and ampicillin is in the plates, the plates are less than a week old and have been stored in the fridge. Only thing I'm not sure about is the ligase or its buffer.

Comment: How far from the end of your PCR product are the restriction sites located?

Comment: @Chris The short end is only three nucleotides, which concerns me a little because other sources I've read suggest I should use 6, but I've gotten away with 3 before, but those used other restriction enzymes, maybe BamHI is a little more sensitive.

Comment: Hmm. According to [NEB](https://www.neb.com/tools-and-resources/usage-guidelines/cleavage-close-to-the-end-of-dna-fragments) this should be ok.

Comment: Could it be due to low transformation efficiency? Have you tried higher competency cells?

Comment: @MarchHo No, just standard subcloning DH5 Alpha E. coli so far. Might see if I can borrow a tube of better cells from another lab, our on campus store makes me buy a whole box of the better cells, but I can get the subcloning cells 1 tube at a time for less money.

Comment: One more question, have you checked your primer's BamHI site directionality? If the sticky ends produced are in the wrong orientation, it can explain the poor ligation.

Comment: @MarchHo That might be it, I just looked at the primer sequences and tried to draw what the overhangs would look like and I think I got one of the sites flipped. Primer 1 is 5' GGATCC 3' and primer 2 is also 5' GGATCC 3'. I think if I get another primer with the CCTAGG orientation this might work better. Alternatively I could trim the overhangs down with klenow and try blunt end ligation.

Comment: @MarchHo After thinking about it a little more and writing the sequences on strips of paper, cutting the ends and wrapping them in a circle, I'm not so sure I was wrong the first time. Either way, I already ordered the new primer, will give it a try.

Comment: The recognition sequences of type II restriction enzymes are palindromic, so if you always read the sequence of each strand from 5' to 3' prime it will always be the same sequence. If, reading from 5' to 3' you specified the sequence CCTAGG then after PCR there would be absolutely no overhanging sticky ends on that end of the fragment. It would be completely blunt. BamHI cannot recognize or cut CCTAGG.